# Intento de inicio de sesión no válido, después de habilitar UserName en MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy creando mi primer proyecto mvc 5 y habilité el logín que trae mvc. Pero quiero que en lugar del correo se muestre el usuario al iniciar sesión así que agregué en el modelo el campo:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Nombre Usuario")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Luego en la vista también.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
```

Y en el controlador  `AccountControllers`  en el Action Register lo cambié a:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email }
```

Pero desde que hice estos cambios no me permite iniciar sesión y me muestra el mensaje: Intento de inicio de sesión no válido.

Luego creé otro usuario con `UserName = Email` ambos igual y así si me permite entrar, pero no entiendo porqué o que tengo que hacer para que me permita registrar el username  y el logeo sea con el email pero que me muestre en la sesión el username.

Answer (score 5):

en el controlador del Login
cambia de

```js
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

a:

```js
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

algo asi:

```js
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
   Email=RegisterViewModel.Email,
   UserName= RegisterViewModel.UserName,
}
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, RegisterViewModel.Password);
```

en la clase  RegisterViewModel agregas UserName

```js
public class RegisterViewModel
{
        public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

en la vista

```js
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Antonio! El detalle es que quiero que se registre con usuario password e email , al hacer login lo haga con email, pero que en la sesión se muestre su usuario y no su email que es como viene por defecto.

Comment: listo ya esta editada